# Determine if the series converges absolutely, conditionally, or diverges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence, conditional-convergence

Determine if the series converges absolutely, converges conditionally, or diverges. Find the exact value for the sum of the convergent series.
$$1-\frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{5^2} + \frac{1}{5^3} - \frac{1}{5^4} - \frac{1}{5^5} + \frac{1}{5^6} - \frac{1}{5^7} - \frac{1}{5^8} ...$$
I have no clue where to start. I tried using the comparison test comparing this series to the series to the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}= 2$ but that only tells me that this is a convergent series, not what value it converges to or if it is absolutely convergent or conditional convergent. Any advice and tips on how to solve this problem and these types of in general would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: It is already absolutely convergent by the comparison test. Are you familiar with the [Geometric Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series

Answer (score 1):

This converges absolutely if you compare with the geometric series with $r = 1/5$. More specifically, it is less than
$$
\sum_{i \ge 0} (1/5)^i = \frac {1}{1-1/5}
$$

Comment: Wow. Cannot believe I hadn't considered the geometric series. It's been a long night. Huge thank you to everyone who replied

Comment: @ToddJones To find the value of the series, note that you original series is *also* a geometric series, with $r=-1/5$ (and with the whole series multipied by $-1$).

Comment: @Clement: I don't think that is quite correct. The series always has one positive and two negative terms. So I guess one needs to subtract two geometric series from each other (or something similar).

Comment: @PhoemueX ouch, my bad, I misread the OP's series. I thought the signs were alternating...